# Object relationships in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an array with objects, and I need to use a value from a key inside of it to search another array, like getting the name of the item ID.

The main array:

```
this.setState({ offers: [
    {
        "name": "Hello World",
        "description": "Goodbye World",
        "item": {
            "value": 1,
            "label": "Í'm a label",
            "type": 44
        },
        "action": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Hello World",
        "description": "Goodbye World",
        "item": {
            "value": 2,
            "label": "Í'm a label",
            "type": 44
        },
        "action": 2
    },
]});
```

And the item array:

```
this.setState({ items: [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "I'm an item!",
        "description": "I'm the item description!"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "I'm an item too!",
        "description": "I'm the item description too!"
    }
]});
```

In react, to display the main array, I do the following:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Col>
            {(this.state.offers && this.state.offers.length > 0) ? (
                this.state.offers.map(offer => this.renderOffer(offer))
            ) : (
                <p>Loading...</p>
            )}
        </Col>
    );
}

renderOffer(product) {
    console.log(product.description) // This would print "Goodbye world"
}
```

But this only let's me get the data of the main array, and I still need to list the item name/item description of every item. I'm looking for something like `product.item.name` which would get the `name` key from my second array, based on the ID that is currently listed in each item in `renderOffer`.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `renderOffer()` just [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the item with the id that matches that offer.

```
renderOffer(product) {
  const item = this.state.items.find(item => item.id === product.item.value)
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>{product.name}</li> // <- Hello World
      <li>{item.name}</li> // <- I'm an item!
    </ul>
  )
}
```

Comment: OP could also apply your answer to reduce the initial `offers` array into a new easy-to-use collection that includes the _item_ inlined in each _offer_.